# ¿Como crear un doble buffer para dibujar en WM_PAINT con transparencia con Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Cree una ventana (que solo tiene el estilo extendido WS_CHILD) que tenía un fondo transparente pintado con `HOLLOW_BRUSH` el problema es que para evitar el parpadeo ví que la mejor opción era crear un buffer antes de que empezase a pintar con el dibujo en el y simplemente pasar lo que había en el buffer al HDC encargado de pintar con `BitBlt`. El problema es que la transparencia que había creado con `HOLLOW_BRUSH` ya no funciona y lo que debería ser transparente pasa a ser negro. Este es mi codigo(TV contiene el tamaño de la ventana):

```
case WM_PAINT:
  
    HDC HDc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT cuadroVentana = {0,0,TV.ancho+4,TV.alto+4};

    Gdiplus::Font fuente(EstiloTexto.c_str(), (Gdiplus::REAL)tamañoLetra, 
    Gdiplus::FontStyleRegular, Gdiplus::UnitPoint);

    Gdiplus::SolidBrush pincel(color_fondo);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush mascara(Gdiplus::Color::Color(200,0,255,0));
    Gdiplus::Pen boli(color_borde,(Gdiplus::REAL)borde);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush boliTexto(colorTexto);

    HDc = BeginPaint(identificador, &ps);//Empieza a pintar obteniendo un contexto de dispositivo

    Gdiplus::Graphics lienzo (HDc);//Creo un objeto para pintar con GDI++ con el contexto de dispositivo

    Gdiplus::RectF rectangu(0, 0, TV.ancho + 4, TV.alto + 4);
    FillRect(buffer, &cuadroVentana, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
 
    lienzo.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias); //Hago que los dibujos de GDI++ tengan suavizado de bordes

    if (borde != 0 && VBorde) //VBorde es una variable bool que indica si hay que pintar un borde y borde es el tamaño del borde
    {
        lienzo.FillPath(&pincel, &graficosGdiF);//relleno el fondo

        lienzo.DrawPath(&boli, &graficosGdiB); // pinto el borde
    }
    else //Si no hay que pintar un borde se pinta la figura completa sin tener en cuenta la parte que tapa el borde
    {
        lienzo.FillPath(&pincel, &graficosGdiF);//relleno el fondo
    }

    if (enInterior)
    {
        lienzo.FillPath(&mascara, &graficosGdiF);
    }

    lienzo.DrawString(texto.c_str(), -1, &fuente, cuadradoText, &formatoTexto, &boliTexto); //pinta un texto

    EndPaint(identificador, &ps); //acabo el dibujo
```

El buffer lo quería hacer así:

```
case WM_PAINT:

   HDC HDc,buffer,aux;
   HBITMAP pantallaBuffer;
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    aux = GetDC(identificador);
    buffer = CreateCompatibleDC(aux);
    pantallaBuffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap(aux,TV.ancho+4,TV.alto+4);
    SelectObject(buffer,pantallaBuffer);

    Gdiplus::Graphics graficosAux(buffer);
    //pintar lo que haya que pintat en el HDC buffer con graficosAux. 

     HDc = BeginPaint(identificador, &ps);
     
     BitBlt(HDc, 0, 0, TV.ancho+4,TV.alto+4, buffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 
 
     EndPaint(identificador, &ps);
   
    DeleteDC(aux);
    DeleteDC(buffer);
    DeleteObject(pantallaBuffer);
```

Comment: Las preguntas que hago sobre winAPI no me las responde nadie. ¿Tengo más posibiliades de que las respondan en stackoverflow que no es español?

Comment: Puedes ver que hay 27 preguntas en todo Stackoverflow en Español con la etiqueta winapi https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi En Stackoverflow tienes casi 40000 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi). Quizá te sea de más ayuda allí.

Comment: @Adrián Supongo que allí tengo que hacer las preguntas en ingles no? esque nunca he entrado muy poco y siempre que lo hago es para leer preguntas y se me traducen

Comment: Sí, estás en lo correcto. En cada plataforma de stackoverflow con X idioma hay que hacerlo con ese idioma. En ese caso inglés.

Comment: Sobre lo de que nadie te responde, tengo conocimientos sobre Windows Forms que al final es una especie de wrapper a la API en C++. Me gustaría ayudarte pero me falta experiencia programando este tipo de aplicaciones en C++.

Comment: ¿Has considerado dibujar lo que quieres en una imagen y luego dibujar la imagen a la ventana? Como sugieren aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/3895365/13419694

Comment: @Mateo no pasa nada . Pero gracias por por lo menos leer mi pregunta para ver si me puedes ayudar. Y lo del mapa de bits es lo que estoy intentando con la variable HBITMAP pantallaBuffer; lo que no consigo es poner transparencia en ese mapa de bits pero miraré en el enlace que ponen en la segunda respuesta porque a lo mejor lo dicen

Comment: ¿Será que se te está olvidando la transparencia? Podrías intentar con `CreateBitmap`. Quizá esto ayude https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563452/13419694